# Java Regex Match \n

Tags: java, regex

First of all, thanks for reading this post because I am really at the end of my tether. I have a set of Patterns and I want to match a string piece by piece. Let's say for example I have two patterns:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)");
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("^(\n)");
```

When I now create a matcher for each pattern, supply it with my input, check if the matcher finds something, and if so replace the input, a \n is never found.

When I for example have the following string as input:
"Hello\nworld"
Pattern1 will find something but the \n is just skipped.

I even tried \\n as pattern but it still does not work.

Thanks,
I really hope you can help me!

Comment: `\n` as a pattern will match in `"Hello\nworld"` if you use `Matcher#find()`.

Comment: Yes I know but I want the next bit of the string matched I want it to only match \n when the string currently starts with it. So I want it to match Pattern1, then the \n and then Pattern1 again. Thats why I put a ^ at the start of the \n.

Comment: If you want to match only the beginning of the line, try "^" see: https://howtodoinjava.com/regex/word-boundary-starts-ends-with/

Comment: I am doing that already, the thing is, I want the input to the matcher to start with a \n but that does not work: ^(\n).

Comment: Just to be clear - User inputs foobar\nmoobar, with a literal slash and n, and, you want the stuff before the \n and the stuff after the \n in separate strings?  Would you be open to one regex with groups to capture the before and after?

Comment: I want a regex that matches the \n itself. So I have pattern1 as explained in the question and pattern2. I use the matcher#replaceFirst function to get rid of the matched stuff at the start of the line. So the input foobar\nmoobar should be matched like this: First I try the first pattern if it finds something use replaceFirst if not try the second pattern so at the end I should have three matches the first one should be "foobar", the second one "\n" and the third one "moobar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem. I was using the string trim method after grouping everything using a matcher. And this function replaces not only spaces when strings start/end with them but also \n.

Still, thanks to everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out for size

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    String testString = "Hello\\nWorld";
    System.out.println(testString);

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9]*)([\\\\]n)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(testString);
    System.out.println(m.matches());
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
  }
```

Group 1 is before the \n, group 2 is the \n, group 3 is after the \n.  There are two levels of escaping going on, if I can read my own code correctly.  To be honest I had an intuition there was an escaping problem and just added slashes until it went away - Haven't had coffee yet today.